# Can Django Blocks have Template Tags?

Tags: django, templates

I'm building a static site generator with a blog plugin. Is there a way I can parse an entire block of contents through markdown like this?

```
title: My First Post
author: Plutor Heidepeen
date: 01-01-2012

{% extends "post.html" %}
{% block body|markdown %}

## This Should be A Title

1. This
2. A
3. List

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`{% filter %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#filter).

```
{% filter markdown %}

## This Should be A Title

1. This
2. A
3. List

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

{% endfilter %}
```